# Flot or Flotr2 CandleStick with Lines (combine series)

Tags: javascript, charts, flot, flotr2

The example can be viewed at http://jsfiddle.net/amnon/njXD3/1/

In the above short example, the code that draws the candlesticks:

```
var p2 = $.plot($("#placeholder"), data2, options2);
```

will draw over the line chart created earlier by

```
var p1 = $.plot($("#placeholder"), data1, options1);
```

i.e commenting out the last $.plot will display the line chart while leaving it uncommented will display the candlestick chart.

The question: What's the simplest way to merge data1, data2, options1, options2 so that the two charts can be combined together in one display? Can it be done with one $.plot? I've tried different variations but without much success.

Alternatively, providing a solution using flotr2 instead (example at http://jsfiddle.net/amnon/dDth9/) would also help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[An example from the plugin page](http://jsfiddle.net/jumjum/EZy3q/) shows how to combine several charts.

As to your code, call the `push` function of your candlestick data with `lines:{show: true}` option.
Here is what you should do:

```
var data2 = $.plot.candlestick.createCandlestick({data:dt,candlestick:{show:true,lineWidth:lw}});

data2.push({ data: prices1, lines:{show: true}, points:{show:true}});
```

And then use `data2` from the code above and `options2`:

```
var p = $.plot($("#placeholder"), data2, options2);
```

Comment: The joke is that I originally took my example from the plugin page you linked to, stripped it so that it only had the candlesticks and then forgot that it had two combined charts when I was trying to figure out how to combine it with another chart :) Anyway, thanks a lot!